How to receive a list of objects on Spring Boot on a multipart request
I have the following route on my API:
@PostMapping(value = "createParnter", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<String> createPartner(
        @ModelAttribute PartnerRequest partnerRequest
) 

The DTOs for the request are the following:
record Contacts(
        String name,
        String email,
) {}

public record PartnerRequest(
        String name,
        MultipartFile logo,
        String link,
        List<Contact> contacts
){}

Sending only the non-list fields via postman, I get a successful request:

However, if I try to send the Contact list together, I get some kind of conversion error:
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.dto.Contacts' for property 'contacts[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
Example of Contact list JSON:
[{"name": "testName", "email": "testEmail}]

I didn't find anything about sending a list of objects (just files) on SO or places like Reddit, etc. GPT couldn't give any working answer as well

Spring is trying to convert the string [{"name": "testName", "email": "testEmail}] to a contact list List<Contact>, but it doesn't know how to do it. You need to help it do it with a converter:
@Component
public class StringToContactListConverter implements Converter<String, List<Contact>> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public List<Contact> convert(String source) {
        try {
            TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
            CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class);
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, collectionType);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error converting " + source + " to contact list", exception);
        }
    }
}

